# How to convert certain columns only to numeric?

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I convert **certain** columns only in a data frame to numeric?

For instance, I have this data frame:

```
structure(list(airport = c("EGLL", "EGLL"), xdate = c("2016-07-28", 
"2016-07-31"), ws = c("6", "5"), wd = c("237", "299"), humidity = c("68", 
"55")), .Names = c("airport", "xdate", "ws", "wd", "humidity"
), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

I just want to convert `ws`, `wd`, and `humidity` to numeric, **not** `airport and xdate`.

If I do this:

```
columns <- sapply(weatherDF, is.character)
weatherDF[, columns] <- lapply(weatherDF[, columns, drop = FALSE], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

I am converting `airport` and `xdate` to numberic, and then I get this warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

And now my data frame has become:

```
structure(list(airport = c(NA_real_, NA_real_), xdate = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_), ws = c(6, 5), wd = c(237, 299), humidity = c(68, 55
)), .Names = c("airport", "xdate", "ws", "wd", "humidity"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Any ideas how I can convert them properly?

Comment: @Batanichek I know all my columns is character. That's my in my question I just want to pick certain columns only.

Comment: `weatherDF[] <- lapply(weatherDF, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1) All your `columns` is `character`
 `columns <- sapply(weatherDF, is.character)`

```
airport    xdate       ws       wd humidity 
    TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE
```

2) Why not simply ?

`weatherDF[, 3:ncol(weatherDF)] <- lapply(3:ncol(weatherDF), function(x) as.numeric(weatherDF[[x]]))`

or

```
columns <-c("ws", "wd", "humidity")
weatherDF[, columns] <- lapply(columns, function(x) as.numeric(weatherDF[[x]]))
```

If your dont know which columns is numeric you can try to find it using `tryCatch`
like

```
weatherDF[,1:ncol(weatherDF)]=lapply(1:ncol(weatherDF),function(x) {
  tryCatch({
    as.numeric(weatherDF[[x]])
    },warning = function(w) {
    weatherDF[[x]]}
        )} )
```

Comment: to get columns from 3 ( without 1 and 2) .. or you wnat to convert to numeric all columns which can be converted?

Answer (score 15):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(ws, wd, humidity), as.numeric)

# A tibble: 2 x 5
airport xdate         ws    wd humidity
  <chr>   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 EGLL    2016-07-28    6.  237.      68.
2 EGLL    2016-07-31    5.  299.      55.
```

Answer (score 8):

```
num.cols <- c('ws','wd','humidity')
weatherDF[num.cols] <- sapply(weatherDF[num.cols], as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `all.is.numeric` function from the [Hmisc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) package does a good job determining whether a given column can be cast to numeric.

Using this, you could do:

```
numeric_cols <- sapply(weatherDF, Hmisc::all.is.numeric)

if (sum(numeric_cols) > 1)  {
    weatherDF[,numeric_cols] <- data.matrix(weatherDF[,numeric_cols])
} else {
    weatherDF[,numeric_cols] <- as.numeric(weatherDF[,numeric_cols])
}
```